# PHPUnit tests are not running using laravel 6.0 with SQLite database

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, pdo

this is my config/database will be if i can get prompt reply

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ]
```

...this is the phpunit.ml.....

```
 <testsuite name="Feature">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
     <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
</php>
```

this is the test.php 
has created database.sqlite already pls what am i missing here am confused

```
namespace Tests\Feature;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ThreadTest extends TestCase
 {
   use DatabaseMigrations ;

  public function a_user_can_browse_threads()
 {
     $thread=factory('App\Thread')->create();
     $response = $this->get('/threads');

     $response->assertSee($thread->title);

     };
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't know that method is a test method most likely

Comment: pls can you be more elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Have you browsed [the documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.4/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) for this?

> *The tests are public methods that are named test*.*

Try using the following:

```
public function testUserCanBrowseThreads() // <-- note the camelCase
{
    $thread = factory(\App\Thread::class)->create();

    $response = $this->get('/threads');

    $response->assertStatus(200); // <-- did you view the thread?

    $response->assertSee($value); //<-- whatever you want to look for 
}
```

You can always write a function *not* named `test*` and consume it another.

```
// This won't run by itself
public function fooBar()
{
    $foo = factory(\App\Foo::class)->create();

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('foos', [
        'id' => $foo->id
    ]);

    return $foo;
}


// This will 
public function testFoo()
{
    $bar = $this->fooBar();

    // Use the information in your test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your test method's name with `test` or add a `@test` annotation in a docblock for the method:

```
public function test_a_user_can_browse_threads()
{
    // Starting the tests name with 'test'
}

public function testUserCanBrowseThreads()
{
    // Starting the tests name with 'test' in another format
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function a_user_can_browse_threads()
{
    // Using the @test annotation
}
```

[PHPUnit Docs - Writing Tests](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.4/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)

Comment: I might be mistaken here, but aren't the test names supposed to be camelCase? Perhaps just a preferential thing?

Comment: Learn something new every day! +1 for the tip.

Comment: probably looks nicer in camelCase though :)

Comment: "this does not work" ... thanks but yes "it does work", try again

Answer (score 0):

have resolved it

./vendor/bin/phpunit did the trick.. calling phpunit direct doesn't work for most latest laravel versio